# Global - Local difference in the init of an array in c

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Why this dont work:

```
int size = 2;
int array[size];

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

It says the error: `array bound is not an integer constant`

And this work:

```
int size = 2;

int main() {
  int array[size];
  return 0;
}
```

Anyone knows the reason?
thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++ or C89/90 neither works. These languages require that array size is an Integral Constant Expression (ICE). In your examples `size` is not an ICE. If your C++ or C89/90 compiler allows it, it is nothing else than a non-standard compiler extension.

In C99 the second works because this is how Variable Array Length (VLA) specification is defined. VLA can only be defined in local scope.

Comment: Remember that VLA are allocated on the stack. While its fine for small datasets, its not a substitute for heap allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic sized arrays is a feature of C99 and is not included in the current C++ standard at all.

If you are compiling as C++ neither should work.  If you change to a const variable then both methods will be allowed by the C++ standard.

Comment: no, if I compile with g++ or gcc and name it .cpp I get the same problem, why!